# differentiability of function at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I have to check differentiability of the following function at 0
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x\ln2}-\frac{1}{2^x-1} & \text{for } x\neq 0 \\
     1/2 & \text{for }x=0 \end{cases} $$
I tried using L'hospital rule but did not get the solution. Any Help will be appreciated

From Hint:
$lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\frac{1}{xln2}-\frac{1}{2^x-1}-1/2}{x}$=$lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\frac{1}{xln2}(\frac{1}{2 - x\ln2}-1/2)}{x}$=$\frac{-\ln 2}{4} $ but answer was $\frac{-\ln 2}{12} $ where is my mistake happen? Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Using $2^h-1=h\log(2)+\frac12(h\log(2))^2+\frac16(\log(2)h)^3+O(h^4)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{h\log(2)}-\frac{1}{2^h-1}-\frac12}{h}\\\\
&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(2-\log(2)h)(2^h-1)-2\log(2)h}{2h^2(2^h-1)\log(2)}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(2-\log(2)h)(h\log(2)+\frac12(h\log(2))^2+\frac16(\log(2)h)^3+O(h^4))-2\log(2)h}{2\log(2)h^2((\log(2)h)+O(h^2))}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-\frac16(\log(2)h)^3+O(h^4)}{2\log^2(2)h^3+O(h^4)}\\\\
&=-\frac{\log(2)}{12}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 0):

HINT : 
$$2^x-1=e^{x\ln(2)}-1\underset{(0)}{=}x\ln\left(2\right)+x^2\frac{(ln(2))^2}{2}+o\left(x^2\right)
$$

Comment: Sir, what is the meaning of =(0) Please tell me?

Comment: is it mean approximation at 0?

Comment: This development is true near $0$